# Why do I have to install CLT when Xcode is installed?

Tags: xcode, command-line, homebrew

On a fresh Mavericks, I installed Xcode via the App store (accepted license agreement and enabled developer mode). After that, Command Line Tools (CLT) are found (`checked via xcode-select -p`). Installing Homebrew as explained on their webpage (`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`) will result in the request to install the CLT. Why do I have to install them? I thought they are installed together with Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install them because, starting with version 4.3, Xcode is released as a sandboxed, **single app bundle**.

Before that, Xcode [was distributed as an installer](http://malcontentcomics.com/systemsboy/2011/03/installing-xcode-4-from-the-app-store.html) called *Install Xcode.app*. The installer had access to the whole filesystem and created a `/Developer` directory, where frameworks and additional tools where placed, and installed the command line tools in `/usr/bin`.

This is no longer the case. Apple chose to make XCode a **standard** Mac App Store app that installs in `/Applications` and requires user intervention to install any additional components outside the bundle container.

Answer (score 2):

The command line tools are not installed as part of Xcode. `xcode-select` does not prove the existence of the command line tools. You have to install them separately.

Comment: I also checked if `gcc --version` responds. It did.