# How to install Homebrew without Command Line Tools if already have Xcode

Tags: homebrew

I already have Xcode installed and want to install Homebrew. It wants to install Xcode Command Line Tools and I don't have space.  Is there a way to install Homebrew without it trying to install the Command Line Tools?

Comment: If there is insufficient space for the one, there may not be room for the other.  Time to do some cleaning or get a bigger disk.

Comment: If I already have Xcode installed, the install script should recognize that and not download and install the Command Line Tools.  I am working with someone who have 256G MacBook Air and a slow internet connection. They did some cleaning, but still have slow internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer by [searching the Homebrew Github Closed Issues for "Xcode"](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Xcode+is%3Aclosed):

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10714

Homebrew requires Xcode Command Line Tools instead of Xcode for several reasons:

- The CLT contains more SDKs than Xcode - Xcode usually only contains
  one SDK, and it may be newer than your OS, while the CLT always has a
  compatible SDK. Having a matching SDK is very important for some
  formulae.
- The CLT is in a fixed location
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools while Xcode is not. This matters
  as some formulae (including Python) bake in paths into files at
  compile-time - if they pointed to Xcode then it will only work for
  people who have Xcode installed in the same place.

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10714

Comment: Kindly remove this answer in favor of [this solution to bypass CLT](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414875/how-to-install-homebrew-without-command-line-tools-if-already-have-xcode#471061)

Answer (score 1):

Apple's website for downloading developer tools says that "If you use Xcode, these tools are already embedded in the IDE."

So you shouldn't need to install them again.

But, as mentioned in the commments: it's a 460 Mb download. If you don't have space for that, you're not going to have space for HomeBrew, or any of the things it installs.

Comment: After every update of XCode, the next time I use it, it asks me whether I want to install the command line tools.  I consider that a bug, and reported such to Apple.  And homebrew needs those tools to compile and link the things it installs.

Comment: I call it a bug because (1) it contradicts Apple’s claim (see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120572/why-do-i-have-to-install-clt-when-xcode-is-installed?rq=1) and (2) the first time I did it (before bundling), my decision should have been stored and made automatic on the next update.

Comment: Xcode has a panel in its Preferences for Locations, which includes the location of the Command Line Tools. Mine is set to inside the application bundle.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: It requires 4GB disk space after installation

Comment: @Nik you are luky because in my case after issuing  `xcode-select --install` a prompt appeared asking for 17 GB of disk space. This is ridiculous because I already have Xcode and its folder takes exactly 17 GB of disk space.

Comment: @Bemipefe that's really strange :/

Comment: 2024-02-21: now  xcode-cli wants *20 GB* of disk space. wtf

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew on a Mac can be installed without Xcode Command Line tools. Technically, Git is the only requirement for the initial Homebrew installation. Then, you can  use Homebrew to install all packages required by other packages/formulae.

1. Install a temporary Git independently ([see Binary installer](https://git-scm.com/download/mac)).
2. Download and save **install.sh** from https://brew.sh. Make the following change to it:

   ```bash
   # USABLE_GIT=/usr/bin/git      # Xcode CLT Git
   USABLE_GIT=/usr/local/bin/git  # Your temporary Git
   ```
3. Install Homebrew `/bin/bash -c install.sh`
4. Delete your temporary Git.
5. Install Git with Homebrew `brew install git`
6. Modify local file  [/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/a3e5e3f7a0e98fe8ffbd8894a9ea0c1fb5c9884f/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb#L277-L280):

   ```ruby
   def self.installed?
     true  # Override Homebrew's CLT check
     # odeprecated "`MacOS::CLT.installed?` on Linux" if Homebrew::SimulateSystem.simulating_or_running_on_linux?
     # !version.null?
   end
   ```

Overriding `self.installed?` ensures that you can install packages that would otherwise require it (i.e. `brew install python`). You'll need to version this change to prevent it from being overridden during `brew update`. For example, using a separate git branch

```bash
git checkout -b my-custom-changes              # new branch
git commit -am "bypass Xcode CLT detection"    # commit changes
```